# Make HD trailer for Unity game

Tags: unity, marketing, trailer

I am making a HD trailer for my Unity game. How do I record awesome HD shots of my game inside the Unity editor?

Comment: Misg trailers aren't made with the game itself

Comment: I removed two sub-questions from your question because the first was asking for a software recommendation, which is off-topic here (try [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-editing)) and the second because it was not an objectively answerable question (questions on stackexchange should be asked in a way which can be answered "right" or "wrong").

Comment: It's not clear to me why you want to do this inside the Unity editor. Trailers would typically be captured using screen recording software and a standalone build of the game. If that's not suitable for your case, can you elaborate on why?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily [capture 4K screenshots in Unity](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/22954/how-to-save-a-picture-take-screenshot-from-a-camer.html). All you have to do is capturing enough of these and assemble them into a video. Adobe Premiere is great for that (no doubt that After Effect can do the same).

The problem with this technique is that the frame rate will be awful if you don't have a powerful computer (taking screenshots costs a lot, but look at [Time.captureFramerate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-captureFramerate.html) to lock the deltaTime value it may smooth the framerate considerably).

Also what you can do is writing a script that will record your inputs and then replay them later on its own. Then you'll just have to play the section you want in your trailer, build your game, play it in HD and record the screen (using camtasia or sharex).

Answer (score 0):

- If you want the screenshots for branding or publishing purpose, you could do some Photoshop on the screenshot.
- You already know the tool. There are other tools like [Fraps](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=fraps) (which is a professional game video capture tool, you can change the fps in it), [PlayClaw](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=PlayClaw&oq=PlayClaw&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.391j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8),  [CamStudio](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=CamStudio), and [VirtualDub](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=VirtualDub).
- Try this [link](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/24122)

You could always use a screen recorder tool to record your screen instantly. Hope this helps :)

Comment: You aren't suggesting to fabricate [bullshots](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bullshot) and then try to pass them off as actual ingame screenshots, are you?